# Casting from class to interface in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel 2013, I have two classes: `LoadCase` and `LoadCombination`, which implement interface `ILoadCase`.

The declaration for `ILoadCase` is:

```
Option Explicit

'' Public properties
Public Property Get Name() As String
End Property
Public Property Let Name(ByVal value As String)
End Property


Public Property Get ID() As Long
End Property
Public Property Let ID(ByVal valus As Long)
End Property
```

And the (partial) implementations for both `LoadCase` and `LoadCombination` are:

```
Option Explicit
Implements ILoadCase

'' Public properties
Public Property Get ILoadCase_Name() As String
    ILoadCase_Name = pName
End Property
Private Property Let ILoadCase_Name(ByVal value As String)
    pName = value
End Property

Public Property Get ILoadCase_ID() As Long
    ILoadCase_ID = pID
End Property
Private Property Let ILoadCase_ID(ByVal value As Long)
    pID = value
End Property
```

I've omitted code which is irrelevant to the implementation of the interface.

I then have a class `BeamForces`, which contains results for a particular `ILoadCase` object:

```
Option Explicit

Public Fx As Double
Public Fy As Double
Public Fz As Double
Public Mx As Double
Public My As Double
Public Mz As Double
Public ParentLoadCase As ILoadCase
```

I thought that with this I'd be able to do something like this:

```
Set currentBeamForces = New BeamForces
With currentBeamForces
    .Fx = forces(0)
    .Fy = forces(1)
    .Fz = forces(2)
    .Mx = forces(3)
    .My = forces(4)
    .Mz = forces(5)
    Set .ParentLoadCase = TargetLoadCase
End With
```

Where `TargetLoadCase` is either a `LoadCase` or a `LoadCombination`, but this gives me an error every time.

I've coded this like I would in .NET and just expected that it would work, but does casting to an interface not work in VBA? Or am I going wrong here somewhere?

**EDIT**

More details. I first call the following method:

```
Public Function LoadBeamForcesAtNode(ByVal TargetBeam As Beam, ByVal TargetNode As Node, Optional ByVal TargetLoadCases As Collection = Nothing) As Boolean

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim currentLoadCase As Variant
    Dim targetBeamForces As BeamForces

    If TargetLoadCases Is Nothing Then
        For Each currentLoadCase In Me.LoadCases.Items
            Call TargetLoadCases.Add(currentLoadCase)
        Next
        For Each currentLoadCase In Me.LoadCombinations.Items
            Call TargetLoadCases.Add(currentLoadCase)
        Next
    End If

    'On Error GoTo ExitPoint
    For Each currentLoadCase In TargetLoadCases
        Set targetBeamForces = InstantiateBeamForces(TargetBeam, TargetNode, currentLoadCase)
        If TargetNode Is TargetBeam.Node1 Then
            Set TargetBeam.Forces1 = targetBeamForces
        Else
            Set TargetBeam.Forces2 = targetBeamForces
        End If
    Next

    LoadBeamForcesAtNode = True

ExitPoint:
End Function
```

Where `TargetLoadCases` is a collection which can contain both `LoadCase` and `LoadCombination` objects.

The problem occurs in `InstantiateBeamForces`, the code for which is

```
Private Function InstantiateBeamForces(ByVal TargetBeam As Beam, ByVal TargetNode As Node, ByVal TargetLoadCase As Variant) As BeamForces

    Dim forces(5) As Double
    Dim currentBeamForces As BeamForces

        Call Me.output.GetMemberEndForces(TargetBeam.ID, IIf(TargetNode Is TargetBeam.Node1, 0, 1), TargetLoadCase.ILoadCase_ID, forces, 0)
        Set currentBeamForces = New BeamForces
        With currentBeamForces
            .Fx = forces(0)
            .Fy = forces(1)
            .Fz = forces(2)
            .Mx = forces(3)
            .My = forces(4)
            .Mz = forces(5)
            Set .ParentLoadCase = TargetLoadCase
        End With

    Set InstantiateBeamForces = currentBeamForces

End Function
```

Which creates a new `BeamForces` object and populates it with the values returned by the `...GetMemberEndForces(...)` API COM call.
The problem is that the `.ParentLoadCase` property is nothing after the assignment, so I'm assuming an invalid cast...

** EDIT 2 **

Here is a screenshot of `TargetLoadCase` when I put a breakpoint in `InstantiateBeamForces`.

[image]

The `ILoadCase` member is `Nothing`, but I don't get why. Could this be the cause of the problem?

Comment: This should work. At least it does in Office 2007. Can you show how `TargetLoadCase` is created? And what's the error?

Comment: Sure, I'll add that.

Comment: Why are you passing `TargetLoadCase` as a `Variant` instead of an `ILoadCase` to `InstantiateBeamForces`? Edit: Shouldn't matter, I suppose. Actually, I'm not sure "private" types can be passed this way, anyway.

Comment: @Bond, thanks for the comments, I really appreciate it. I originally passed `TargetLoadCase` as `ILoadCase`, but changed it to variant, because I thought maybe that might be the source of the problem. When I passed it as an `ILoadCase`, `TargetLoadCase` was `Nothing` in `InstantiateBeamForces`. Passing as variant, gives an object, but the problem then occurs when I assign `.ParentLoadCase`, so it only shifted the problem unfortunately...

Comment: Try outputting the type of `TargetLoadCase` before the assignment to `ParentLoadCase`. Something like: `MsgBox TypeName(TargetLoadCase)` should work.

Comment: I've been looking at it in the debugger and it is assigned correctly. It says that the `ILoadCase` member is `Nothing` though, which is why I suspect the case gives `Nothing`. I'll put up a screenshot.

Comment: I'm testing using the canonical `IShape` interface with two classes (`CSquare` and `CTriangle`) and I get `Nothing` for the `IShape` member in my debugger, too. But everything still works fine.

Comment: That's interesting... I'm going to have another look through my code based on that to see what's going wrong. I'll report back here.

Comment: In the `Watch` window, under the `Type` column, it should say: `Variant/Object/LoadCase` or `Variant/Object/LoadCombination`. [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/BCeawCe.png) of my test.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting that too. If it works fine for you and not for me, then that means my error must be elsewhere. I'll need a thorough check here. Again, I'll report back. If this clears the error, then I'll take your suggestions as answer (if you post them). I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks, the error was somethign else. I feel like such an idiot :( If you write up the fact that you tried it on your PC and your implementation showed no errors, then I'll take that as answer. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Glad you figured it out!